# Debian 12 VM (on Hyper-V) has eth0/eth1 interface names instead of expected Predictable Network Interface Names?

Tags: debian, networking, systemd-networkd

I've just installed a brand new Debian `12.4.0` VM on a Hyper-V host, using the typical Debian `debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso` image.

Logging in to complete the network setup, I'm surprised to find that my two virtualised NICs are named `eth0` and `eth1` rather than anything following the [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) pattern. I'm concerned that this might mean that `eth0` and `eth1` might not bind to the virtual NICs consistently, which would mess up my static IP address allocations and result in traffic getting routed to the wrong interfaces or tagged with the wrong VLAN IDs.

Debian [wiki for Network Interface Names](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames) says that when I run `udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/eth0 2>/dev/null`, the output should always contain an `ID_NET_NAME_PATH` element:

> **ID_NET_NAME_PATH=** Always present; usually something just complicated enough to be easy to forget, like wlp3s5 or enp1s3f0. Note that all numbers are in hex.

But that's not what I see! When I run that command, I get only the following output:

```
ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=v252
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx00155dddac06
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Microsoft Corporation
```

**The question is:** why aren't these VM network interfaces generating an *ID_NET_NAME_PATH* name according to the "Predictable Interface Names" pattern, and how can I fix that?

**Follow-up question:** If I leave the interface names as `eth0` and `eth1`, is there any *actual* risk that this will result in unstable network interface binding?

##### More information about the current system configuration follows

In the Debian installer, I chose to install without any desktop environment, but *with* an SSH server, since this is to be a remotely-managed server for basic server apps and Docker container hosting, without interactive users. Therefore `NetworkManager` is not present; I believe the network configuration is being managed by `systemd-networkd`.

The new system has no files in `/etc/systemd/network`. So I believe it will be using the the default naming policy order given in `/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link`? That file's contents are:

```
[Match]
OriginalName=*

[Link]
NamePolicy=keep kernel database onboard slot path
AlternativeNamesPolicy=database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
```

The output of `sudo sysctl -a` contains no reference to `net.ifnames`.

Linux version is `Linux [...] 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`. systemd version is `systemd 252 (252.19-1~deb12u1)`.

I have checked the "Virtual Machines" note in the linked Debian NetworkInterfaceNames wiki page, which suggests removing some files under `/etc/systemd/network` and then rebuilding the `initrd` in order to trigger re-generation of the interface names. I have no files in those locations. I tried rebuilding the initrd and rebooting anyway. This had no effect on the interface names; they're still `eth0` and `eth1`.